# Blazor Relative url

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have navlink defined as follows

`<NavLink href="/intro"></NavLink>`

In dev it works fine as the root of the site is at the same level as the blazor app.
In prod I have to put the blazor site inside a folder in the default iis website.
So my url becomes something like this

`http://something/apps/cor/`

So the `<NavLink href="/intro"></NavLink>` ends up trying to go to `http://something/intro` instead `http://something/apps/cor/intro`

I tried both `/intro` and `intro` and the both result in the wrong behavior. I am not getting how to make those links relative to blazor root not iis root.

Answer (score 10):

Dot before the path. `./intro` is how you do it

Comment: Well, I upvoted, but I'm not sure this answer is complete. See the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#app-base-path

Answer (score 5):

on `index.html` you should have `<base href="/apps/cor/" />`

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this trick in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@inject IWebHostEnvironment Environment;

// in <head> :
@if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    <base href="~/" />
}
else
{
    <base href="~/myApp" />
}
```

then either `<NavLink href="page"></NavLink>` or `<NavLink href="./page"></NavLink>` works.

- On localhost: `https://localhost:44393/page`
- On server: `https://example.com/myApp/page`